# Printing local variable and recursive-call parameter in a recursive function. How do I implement it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Objective:
Modify the recursive fibonacci function to print its local variable and recursive-call parameter. For each recursive call, display the outputs on a separate line and add
a level of indentation.

I tried:

```
from pprint import pprint
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1

    pprint(f" fib({fib(n - 1)})")
    pprint(f" fib({fib(n - 2)})")
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)


fib(5)
```

The first problem:

When I call `fib(5)` it does not print fib(5) or fib(4), for example. How can I fix it?

Comment: `print(f'fib({n}), fib({n-1}),fib({n-2})')`

Comment: @ wwii I did not understand! What is the difference?

Comment: ``{fib(n - 1)}`` is the value of ``fib(n - 1)``, not the value of ``n - 1``. ``f" fib({fib(n - 1)})"`` has one ``fib`` too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to embed the result of `fib(n-1)` in your string; you only want `n-1`.

```
from pprint import pprint

def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1

    pprint(f" fib({n - 1})")  # f" fib({fib(n - 1)})"
    pprint(f" fib({n - 2})")
    fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)


fib(5)
```

Comment: `{n-1}` is replaced with the value of `n-1`; `{fib(n-1)}` is replaced with the result of calling `fib(n-1)`.

Comment: Note that the `line` fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)` isn't necessary; you compute the result, discard the result, then evaluate it again with `return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `fib(5)` it can not write `fib(5)`, because `fib(5)` equals `fib(4) + fib(3)`. 
Also, it is really bad modifitaion that you did because you make calls two times. So, I advise you the next code:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        n_minus_one = fib(n - 1)
        n_minus_two = fib(n - 2)

        print(f'call: fib({n-1}) value={n_minus_one}')
        print(f'call: fib({n-2}) value={n_minus_two}')

        return n_minus_one + n_minus_two


print(fib(5))
```

Or if you don`t want to see values:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        print(f'call: fib({n-1})')
        print(f'call: fib({n-2})')

        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


print(fib(5))
```

I hope that I helped you.